# Manhwa where girl is reincarnated as her past self 3 times

Tags: story-identification, manga

So in the start it shows how a little girl (black hair green eyes) chose to marry a duke (blond hair blue eyes) instead of a king (red hair) and said she chose the blond kid "because he's pretty".  It later shows that she has relived her life multiple times: the first time she killed herself after realizing her husband the king gave her stds, the second time she killed herself because she married a poor painter and they killed him and took her baby, and in her current life she is trying to have the blond guy she choose to marry cheat on her so that she can get a divorce and live her life peacefully.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[The Broken Ring: This Marriage Will Fail Anyway](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5o3xoq1/the-broken-ring-this-marriage-will-fail-anyway)***...?

> When six-year-old Inés laid eyes on the handsome heir to House Escalante, she promptly made the boy her fiancé. Since noble men are all the same, she figured she might as well choose a pretty one. But Lord Cárcel isn't ready for this sort of commitment just yet, and he spends the next decade and a half avoiding the marriage at all costs! Luckily, that's no trouble for Inés, as this marriage failing is exactly what she wants. In fact, he has her blessing to sow his wild oats as long as he stays out of her business. Unfortunately, being a playboy isn't as fun when your fiancée gives you permission. And doesn't this mean she's cheating on him too? Now, Cárcel is determined to change Inés' mind about him and prove he can be the husband she's always wanted.

As a young girl, the black-haired, green-eyed female lead turned down a marriage proposal from the red-haired crown prince, choosing to marry a blond-haired lord instead, because he had a pretty face.

It's later revealed that she's in a time loop of some sort, and that in a previous loop, she married the prince and had a series of miscarriages, for which she was blamed. The cause of the miscarriages were STDs that she caught from the prince as a result of his infidelity, and she ultimately took her own life with a rifle.

In a subsequent loop, she ran away with a portrait artist's assistant, but after spending a few years together, he was shot and killed in front of her, and she later committed suicide again.

[image] [image]